Implementing a refresh on screen change in expo router
I am writing a mobile application in React-Native using Expo-router.
I currently have a main screen containing content, that has a path to another screen where users can upload content. On calling router.back() which brings the user back to the main screen, I would like the main screen to refresh with the newly updated content.
Currently, I am confused on the how to implement this, and have been trying to use the useContext hook but it has not been working.
My current code is as follows
Code from MainScreen.tsx responsible for updating content when refresh is set to true:
  const { refresh, setUser, ...user } = useContext(UserContext); // Destructure the needed parts

  const [feedData, setFeedData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [deleteRefresh, setDeleteRefresh] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    console.log("Use effect called with refresh: ", refresh);

    async function getFeedData() {
      const newFeed = await logFeedData();
      if (newFeed) {
        setFeedData(newFeed);
        setUser({refresh: false, ...user})
      } else {
        console.log("No new feed data");
      }
    }
  
    if (refresh) {
      getFeedData();
    }
    console.log("Now setting loading to false");
    setLoading(false);
  }, [refresh]);

Code from the Broadcast.tsx screen responsible for the upload of user content:
const { refresh, setUser, ...user } = useContext(UserContext); // Destructure the needed parts

const BroadcastText: React.FC<BroadcastTextProps> = (setUpdated: any) => {


async function postFeedText(content: string, userId: string) {

  try {
    const response = await post({
    //uploads user data
    ).response;

    const jsonData = await response.body.json();
    console.log("POST body: ", jsonData)

    console.log("Setting user refresh value to true")

    setUser({...user, refresh: true})
    console.log("Refresh value: ", refresh)
    router.back()
    return;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log("err uploading text")
  }
}

And I have my user context defined in my top level _layout.tsx file as follows:
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import { Stack } from "expo-router"
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
export { default as ReactFromModule } from 'react'

import { profileTheme } from './Theme.js';

type UserContextType = {
  userName: string,
  userEmail: string,
  userId: string,
  refresh: boolean,
  setUser: (user: Partial<UserContextType>) => void,
  profilePicPath: string,
  profilePicUrl: string
};

// Initialize with default values
const defaultContextValue: UserContextType = {
  userName: '',
  userEmail: '',
  userId: 'default',
  refresh: false,
  setUser: () => {},
  profilePicPath: '',
  profilePicUrl: ''
};

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>(defaultContextValue);

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserContextType>(defaultContextValue);


  const handleSetUser = (userData: Partial<UserContextType>) => {
    console.log("Context has been called");
    setUser(prevUser => ({
      ...prevUser,
      ...userData
    }));
  };

  console.log("ROOT LAYOUT");

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ ...user, setUser: handleSetUser }}>
      <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {/* Your screens */}
      </Stack>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

If there are issues with the useContext approach, or if there is any other approach that is more efficient/elegant, please let me know. Thank you!

I am not familiar with latest js object updating syntax, however, what if you refactor refresh variable like: const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false); to jsut call setRefresh(true)?

I tried to use useState to create the variable in the main screen using const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);, but then the issue became that I was not sure how to pass the setRefresh function to the other screen that I navigate to. On using expo router, you can only pass a string dictionary as local params to another screen, and not functions

I think you want useFocusEffect https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/hooks/#usefocuseffect
